# System.loadLibrary loads something else

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, runtime, shared-libraries

In my java code, I call `System.loadLibrary(A);` to load the `A.so` library. However, my app crashes at run time with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "B.so" not found
```

Admittedly, the `B.so` library is a dependency of `A.so` library. But I did not explicitly call `System.loadLibrary()` on `B.so` anywhere. I was under the impression that `B.so` will be covered by `A.so`. Why is the Java runtime trying to load `B.so`?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not how dynamic libraries are loaded. You will need to provide both `A.so`, `B.so` and any other shared libraries `B.so` might need.

Comment: The message "dlopen failed" hints that this is the **D**ynamic **L**inker giving you that error.

Comment: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/